# Column Data Type for Bitwise Comparison?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table where I have an int32 column storing values for bitwise comparison. I've ran out int space with a int32. I can convert to int64 but that will just prolong the inevitable. Is there an efficient data type I should store these values in instead of int?

It would be OK to re-assign all my existing values if I have to.

Comment: `VARBINARY(MAX)` ?

Comment: ughh http://stackoverflow.com/questions/809375/sql-server-varbinary-or-int-to-store-a-bit-mask Not what I wanted to read.

Comment: While there are a bunch of people that will disagree with me... Having the choice between bitmasks and something else, I'd choose something else. Even if it was adding in 64 IsBlah columns to the table. Anything that gets away from `magic numbers` or bitmasks. Not knowing how, why, or what, something like a key/value store property bag style could work for you... again, don't know much.

Comment: Why are you using a bit array at all instead of distinct bit flags (datatype *bit*)? Let the RDBMS figure out how to efficiently store the values in a record, and complete the Normalizaiton to **Zeroth Normal Form** by eliminating this repeating group.

Comment: I can see the appeal of using bitmasks and storing them in a single field, but the gain in simplicity of programming comes at the huge cost of losing index ability on the data in question.  If you *must* use a bit field, use several BIGINTS and make do, but I agree with the other commenters that you *should* store data in discrete fields.

Answer (score 0):

I only use flags/bitmask fields in cases where a.) the flatness of the schema matters (data warehouse) and b.) I'm absolutely guaranteed to never pass 64 bits. If this is an OLTP system I'd refactor to use both a many to many mapping table to track the bits and a lookup table with flag names. The m2m table would have 2 fields: FK to the ID of the table currently housing the flags and an FK to a lookup table. The lookup table would be FlagID, FlagName ("Flag" should be replaced with whatever this data actually is "error" maybe). This has the added bonus of greatly simplifying queries and constraints on this data.